# $this->upload->data() doesn't work properly

Tags: codeigniter

I'm a beginner in CodeIgniter. I'm trying to get the properties for one file that I've uploaded, like name, type, etc. But I can't retrieve that information. It's outputing an empty array. Where I'm doing wrong? I tried:

```
function do_upload() {

    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|pdf';
    $config['max_size'] = '999999';
    $config['max_width']  = '3000';
    $config['max_height']  = '2000';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config); 

    $details = $this->upload->data();
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r ($details);
    echo "</pre>";        

    if (!$this->upload->do_upload()){
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
    } else {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
      }
}
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [file_name] => 
    [file_type] => 
    [file_path] => ./uploads/
    [full_path] => ./uploads/
    [raw_name] => 
    [orig_name] => 
    [client_name] => 
    [file_ext] => 
    [file_size] => 
    [is_image] => 
    [image_width] => 
    [image_height] => 
    [image_type] => 
    [image_size_str] => 
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$this->upload->data()` will return the uploaded data after executing the `$this->upload->do_upload()`. So try in your `else` part.

For more details, refer CI user [Guide](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html)

Comment: Thank, you.. i searched for the meaning of this,